# Is optical activity of a given compound a statistical picture?

Tags: organic-chemistry, stereochemistry, optical-properties

When optical activity is taught it is done in terms of single molecules. But when it is actually measured it is done on a large collection of such molecules. So, how does the asymmetry manifest itself as the rotation of plane polarised light. Is it a collective effect of all the molecules put together in a sample or does each molecule play a role?

Comment: Please have a look at the wikipedia article on [specific rotation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specific_rotation) for the effect of concentration and path length on the outcome of the measurement.

Comment: This earlier question and answer, ["How does polarimetry account for the orientation of the molecules?"](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/12300/how-does-polarimetry-account-for-the-orientation-of-the-molecules/12302#12302) may be helpful.